# UIAlertView error undeclared

Tags: ios, uialertview

I'm having my head cracking just to figure out the code error in this problem .

My error : Use of undeclared identifier 'alertView'

appdelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

appdelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Daily Vibes"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

        if([title isEqualToString:@"Okay"])
        {
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
            MyViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
            [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add which line you got the error?

Comment: @Jens , at this line : - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a close bracket for this method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Daily Vibes"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}   // <<<<----------- Here
```

Comment: Holy ... a small mistake which i've never checked..thanks man a correct answer for you coming right up